# Angular2 innerHtml binding remove style attribute

Tags: angular, styles

My problem, that when I use innererHtml binding  - angular2 remove all styles attributes. It's important for me, bacause in my task - html is generated on server-side with all styles.
Example:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="html">
    <div [innerHtml]="html">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  html: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.html = "<span style=\"color:red;\">1234</span>";
  }
}
```

But in DOM I see only 1234 and this text is not red.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQJOFMKl9OwMRIJ38U8D?p=preview

Thank you!

Answer (score 202):

You can leverage `DomSanitized` to avoid it.

The easiest  way is to create custom pipe like:

```typescript
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

So you can use it like:

```html
<div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml"></div>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2z5DS8rgcWWO83KVelei?p=preview)**

Comment: Awesome solution! The only thing I've changed is I added `pure: true` to the `@Pipe` decorator, so that Angular knows not to recalculate it over and over again on every change detection, and does that only if `html` (the input) is changed. At least that's what I figure should be happening :)

Comment: This is really good, however I have one question. I am using Angular Material and for some reason when I try to use Angular Material it doesn't work. For example, if I pass <mat-toolbar><span>Test</span></mat-toolbar> It doesn't actually give me a toolbar, just the text. Any idea on how to get around that?

Thanks

Comment: @DevShadow Angular doesn't parse template at runtime. If you want to do that then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: This can open you up to a XSS attack.

Comment: Bypassing sanitizer to trust any content can be a security concern. Since Angular is not a dedicated sanitizing library, it is overzealous towards suspicious content to not take any risks. It removed almost all attributes, for example. You can delegate sanitizing to a dedicated library — DOMPurify. Here's a wrapper library I've made to easily use DOMPurify with Angular:

https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ng-dompurify

Comment: This creates security concern. Before implementing this solution, please read @a darren answer!

Comment: Awesome! In my case, making ViewEncapsulation.None did not work. But yours solution was spot on. Thanks

Comment: the pipe name should be `unsafeHtml` since it will literally let unsafe html to the dom. There is nothing `safe` in this pipe

Comment: This should have been included in angular core pipes

Answer (score 51):

I improved the example of yurzui a bit by completing the needed imports:

```typescript
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

I also had to add the class in my app.module.ts file

```typescript
import ...
import {SafeHtmlPipe} from "./pipes/safehtml.pipe";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...,
        SafeHtmlPipe  <--
    ],
    imports: [...],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Note that the `sanitizer` has a few methods for *trusting* content e.g.

```js
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(value); // - see docs [1]
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/142714

So, `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` may also be what you want here, as this will show inline styles within your HTML content (`value`).

[1] docs: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. only using `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` is prune to run malicious javascript. If only styles are what you need to bypass, bypass using `bypassSecurityTrustStyle()` is better.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as it is wrong. `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` returns `SafeStyle` and `[innerHTML]` requires `SafeHtml`. If you use it, it throws: `Required a safe HTML, got a Style`. So if you have html content with inline styles a combination of an external sanitizer and `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` like described in below comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute/39630507#comment104193367_39630507) should be the way to go.