# How to use innerHTML on input

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

This works: 
    `<div [innerHTML]="rssItem.title"></div>`

This does not:
     `<input type="text" formControlName="title" [(ngModel)]="rssItem.title" name="title" #title class="form-control" [innerHTML]="rssItem.title">`

Why?

I have attempted using a sanitize html pipe as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute) but it does not work for text input.

Using Angular2 version 2.4.5 on Windows.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with the innerHTML bind?

Comment: Convert this to a html string:
&#39134;&#24605;&#21345;&#23572;&#26368;&#26032;MCU

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to decoding HTML characters ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787/7045253))

```
constructor() {
   let str = "&#39134;&#24605;&#21345;&#23572;&#26368;&#26032;MCU";
   this.rssItem.title = this.decodeHtml(str);
}

private decodeHtml(html: string) {
 var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
 txt.innerHTML = html;
 return txt.value;
}
```

Furthermore, use `Sanitizer` to have the safe html string. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121006/7045253))

Comment: Looks like we came up with same solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Created a private function :

```
decodeEntities(encodedString) {
  var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
  return textArea.value;
}
```

And used it to decode the string.

Tried to create a pipe using the same code but wasn't able to get it to work in the Input Text tag.  If someone has an idea on how to do that please post it.

Comment: Found another solution using the he encoder/decoder (https://www.npmjs.com/package/he) which I think works better.