# Style not working for innerHTML in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am passing html as innerHtml to my view. Below is my view

```
<div [innerHTML]="someHtmlCode"></div>
```

if I pass the below code, it is working fine.

```
this.someHtmlCode = "<div><b>This is my HTML.</b></div>"
```

if I pass the below code which contains color, it is not working.

```
 this.someHtmlCode = '<div style="background-color: blue;"><b>This is my HTML.</b></div>';
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@ahmedhamedTN/make-styles-work-when-dealing-with-innerhtml-in-angular-ac2d524ba001

use this....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute/39630507#39630507
this may help you.

Comment: Check this ideal use case for styles: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustStyle

Answer (score 340, accepted):

This behavior you're getting is normal. The class added to `innerHTML` is ignored because by default the encapsulation is `Emulated`. Which means Angular prevents styles from intercepting inside and outside of the component.
You should change the encapsulation to `None` in your component.
This way, you'll be able to define classes wherever you want: inside `styles` or in a separate `.css`, `.scss` or `.less` style-sheet (it doesn't matter) and Angular will add them to the DOM automatically.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  styles: ['.demo {background-color: blue}'],
  template: '<div [innerHTML]="someHtmlCode"></div>',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Example {
  private someHtmlCode = '';

  constructor() {
    this.someHtmlCode = '<div class="demo"><b>This is my HTML.</b></div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: If I pass just style without class It is not working

Comment: You're right and I couldn't find a solution to make it work :) 
I would advise you however not to use inlined styles as it is not a good practice to have it mixed within the template.

Comment: @Chatra You may want to check out [this](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: `ViewEncapsulation` is a part of angular/core:
`import { ViewEncapsulation  } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Make sure you import ViewEncapsulation from @angular/core and NOT from @angular/compiler/src/core. Otherwise, you will end up with a mysterious error - "Cannot find module 'tslib'"!

Comment: Ohh my God, you're an incarnation. I've been scratching my head on this problem for two days. Thank you very much.

Comment: I get `core.js:1633 ERROR cordova_not_available` in browser, after adding the import of `{ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: You can also use:host ::ng-deep or only ::ng-deep to apply style. You need to declare these modifiers in the style file.

Comment: It's worth noting that changing ViewEncapsulation to None can have pretty far-reaching consequences. This applies your styles globally - so if you set something like a div tag to have a background color, this will change all divs in your app to have that background color. I would steer clear of changing the ViewEncapsulation unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: i have same error. but the content is being fetch from database with inline style.
so how can i solve this.

Comment: The question is about using explicit inline styles, not classes.

Comment: Any solution without viewEncapsulation.None?

Comment: We can also use `::ng-deep` in the styles file, this will do the job without specifying `ViewEncapsulation.None` (i.e. ViewEncapsulation staying on `Emulated` which is the default one). 

Ex: (in component's scss file:) `::ng-deep .demo {color: red}`

Comment: Making Angular component encapsulation none is not good idea. adding CSS class to the global CSS file (it should register in Angular.json) will work perfectly

Comment: What if you're using a pipe and not a component? There's no option for view encapsulation with a pipe, so how would you apply inline style?

Comment: How can this have over 300 upvotes? It's not even replying to the question as it's not working for style, and it's quite dangerous to use as well! The better answer is to use safe html pipes.

Comment: This works even better than ::ng-deep

Answer (score -3):

Instead of an inline style, I put the style in a class.

Not sure if using `class` is an option for you or not, but here's a Plunker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFCcXqmOnj2oxPma6zPg?p=preview).

HTML:

```
this.someHtmlCode = '<div class="demo"><b>This is my HTML.</b></div>'
```

Define the class `demo` at the global root css file, usually it's called `styles.scss`.

CSS:

```
.demo{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: it is not working, Is there any difference if my demo css is in less file?

Comment: This works if the css is in the global styles.css file, but not in a non-global css file.  It would be helpful if someone could explain the difference, but in the meantime I thought I'd post a comment to make others aware that getting this working depends on such details.

Comment: my-angular-component.html has `<div class="my-static-div" [innerHTML]="<div class='my-dynamic-div'>" (click)="handleStaticClick($event)"` ... then in my-angular-component.css use `.my-static-div ::ng-deep .my-dynamic-div { color: blue; }` and my-angular-component.ts `public handleStaticClick(event) { if (event.srcElement.classList.contains('my-dynamic-div')) { this.handleDynamicClick(); }}`

Comment: I solved my issue with this awnser by placing the selector ::ng-deep before the class.

Comment: Actually I solved my problem doing this. I defined a class `.mono { font-family: monospace !important; }` in my `style.scss` and then used it as usual: `<h2 class="mono">Title</h2>`