# How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?

Tags: html, angular, rendering

In my angular 4 app, I have a string like

```
comment: string;
comment = "<p><em><strong>abc</strong></em></p>";
```

When I serve this text in my html, like

```
{{comment}}
```

Then it displays:

```
<p><em><strong>abc</strong></em></p>
```

But I need to display the text "abc" in bold and italic form, like
***abc***

How can I do this?

Answer (score 760, accepted):

Use one way flow syntax **property binding**:

```
<div [innerHTML]="comment"></div>
```

[From angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example): "Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the `<script>` tag but keeps safe content such as the `<b>` element."

Comment: In Angular front-end, using [innerHTML] may lead to security faults, and thus should be disallowed. https://angular.io/guide/security.

Comment: @HongNguyen As I understand it, I think that article you shared explains that it is safer to use [innerHTML]. Check the live example.

Comment: Thanks, but when my HTML be render, the string html generated, show as string, not Input or something like that. what should I do?

Comment: FYI from angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/security): "Angular recognizes the value (`[innerHtml]`) as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the <script> tag but keeps safe content such as the <b> element."

Comment: can i open it in external browser... my inner html is link, i need to when click it open external browser new page. ? how can i do it, my anguler app , run using jx browser.

Comment: @uma yes if your innerhtml has <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">Click here</a> tag. This should work

Comment: this has a drawback: it won't apply css styles to the tags that are in the component css

Comment: @albanx you can add css styles by adding "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None," to your Component. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210786/style-not-working-for-innerhtml-in-angular

Comment: Adding ng-bind-html="value" helped me.

Comment: For simple html content we can use directly `<div [innerHtml]="htmlContent"></div>`, But if you want to use complex html and styles need to use the safeHtml pipes like this `<div id="previewDoc" [innerHTML]="previewDoc | safeHtml" class="preview"></div>` and we need to create the safeHtml pipe.

Comment: @HongNguyen useless comment. disallow and HOW to do that? if projects ask us to do it, what is replacement then?

Comment: @AylaWinters, It is not advisable to use "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" as it affects your global styling which me result in disturbed CSS for other components as well

Comment: @Pipe({ name: "safeHtml" })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}