# Render dynamic HTML inside a ng-Template

Tags: angular

How can I insert a dynamic HTML inside my `ng-template` ? the HTML came from the `TS` as you can see below, but when it renders, appear in string mode `<span class="searchedText">Some Name here</span>`

**HTML**

```
<ng-template #nameTmpl let-value>
  {{ formatName(value) }}
</ng-template>
```

**TS**

```
formatName(name) {
    return name.replace(new RegExp(this.textSearch.toUpperCase(), 'g'),
                `<span class='searchedText'>` + this.textSearch.toUpperCase() + `</span>`);
}
```

Comment: The [innerHTML] tag should work here as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4

Comment: @cyniikal thanks, it works!