# How can get the native DOM element between selector tags in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I want to get the html element between the 2 component selector tags.
Something like this:

```
component A
 template: '<comp-b><div><h1>Hi</h1></div></comp-b>'

component B
 selector:'comp-b'
export class ComponentB{ //I want to get "<div><h1>Hi</h1></div>" as a string }
```

Can anyone help me understand how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, why don't you use CSS int the child component's  `.css` file.

Enclose the component's HTML in a `<div>` or if it's already in a `<div>` assign a class to it like

```
<div class="c1">
    ... 
    <!-- your code here-->  
    ...
</div>
```

and in the `.css` file, define the class and add whatever you want to add. It may look something like this:

```
.c1{
      display: block;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1.1;
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i don't want add css to that element, i  need get all element btw selector tags as string.

Comment: This question might help then https://stackoverflow.com/q/49013217/6438896