# How to use/display string with html tags in typescript

Tags: html, typescript

```
var bannerText = stringFormat("This is my {0}test content{1} here", "<b>", "</b>");
<div>
    <p> {para1}</p>
    <p> {bannerText}</p>
</div>
```

html tags gets printed instead of applying them as text

Observed output

> This is my <b>test content</b> here

Needed output

> This is my **test content** here

Comment: check my answer bro it might help you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 3):

```
<div [innerHTML]="bannerText"></div>
```

However, keep in mind Angular's [docs about security](https://angular.io/guide/security), which says `Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the <script> tag but keeps safe content such as the <b> element.`.

Answer (score 2):

check the below code it might help you.use innerHtml

```js
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="This is <u>my test</u> sample"
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

> `Observed output This is my <u>test content</u> here`

Whatever method you are using is *escaping* the html e.g. `<` / `>` etc.

## Fix

You need some version of *set HTML*.

e.g. React : `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, Pure JS: Use `innerHTML`

## Warning

Be careful, setting html exposes your app to XSS : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting