# I am getting a JSON response with HTML anchor elements, how can I make those elements appear as a link in the response using only Angular7

Tags: html, json, api, angular7, response

I am getting a JSON response back from my API get request.  Within the response, there are some HTML elements like anchor tags and line breaks.

How can I display that response and have those html elements appear as actual elements instead of JSON?

For example, this is part of my response:

```
[
  {
    "commentDescriptions": [
      {
        "commentDescription": "Corrections can be made 24 hours after 
submitting your application by logging back into your application at <a 
href=http://www.somewebsite.org/ style=font-size:inherit;font- 
weight:bold;>www.website.org</a>. You must use your User ID and password to 
retrieve your application. If you need additional help with your application, 
contact the Customer Relations Branch by email at <a 
href=mailto:support@email.com style=font-size:inherit;font- 
weight:bold;>websitelink</a>.<br/> If your mailing address or email address 
changes, you must make the correction on your Application. </br><a 
href=https://www.mywebsite.com/ style=font-size:inherit;font- 
weight:bold;>Click here</a>
      },

    ]
  }
]
```

I cannot use any external libraries, packages or jquery.  All must be done with Angular 7.

Comment: this doesn't seems to be JSON response. Please put complete response or code you used to get this answer.

Comment: I've updated the original post to have the JSON response format

Comment: Great. You need to render HTML. Please check this answer and its links, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4

Comment: Thanks but there was no solution in that link unfortunately.

Comment: One of links suggests: 
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>  
can you use something like that?
I mean, create a div somewhare and assign as above the content in "commentDescriptions" -> "theHtmlString"...
If not possible,  you may need to reconstruct all the content by parsing it somehow and then assign to new components.

Comment: While that link didnt have the answer I was looking for, it led me to a path to an answer.  The solution was to create a custom pipe and use DomSanitizer.  Thank you for the help.