# How to parse HTML from response in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I do request to server and get JSON result:

```
{"result" => "HTML code"}
```

How to parse HTML code and get table from this response?

I tried to place this code to hidden block on the page:

```
<div #content>HTML code here from response</div>
```

What next? How to parse?

Comment: Use the `innerHtml` attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: The div you posted expects text not HTML

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  demo: string = `<div>
 <p>I am Yogesh</p>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </div>`
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I would advise caution on using `innerHTML` as it can create memory leaks

Comment: @JosephBriggs can you say what is the alternative so it's a bit more useful? thanks.

Answer (score 12):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({name: 'sanitizeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {
   }
   transform(value: string) {
     return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
   }
}

Usage:
<div [innerHTML]="content | sanitizeHtml"></div> //Content is what you got from json
```

We should always santize the content to prevent any malicious activity with DOMSanitizer. So for that We can create a pipe as above and use it anywhere in app.

Comment: Aren't you bypassing the built-in sanitization here?

Comment: to sanitize the HTML, in Angular 15: `this.sanitized.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value)`