# Is it possible to create a breakline in HTML via JS string?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

```js
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {

  list: Foo[] = [{name: 'Name 1', groupName: 'Group 1'}, {name: 'Name 1', groupName: 'Group 1'}]
  message = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.confirmRemoval(this.list);
  }

  confirmRemoval(messageList: Foo[]): string {
  return `The following products already belong to a group and will be removed from it: ${messageList.map(v => 
  `- ${v.name} belongs to the group ${v.groupName}`).join("<br/>\n")}. Do you wish to continue?`;
  }
}

export interface Foo {
  name?: string;
  groupName?: string;
}
```

```html
<h3>This is what it looks like: 
</h3>
<p>{{message}}</p>

<h3>What I wanted was to see if I could make the message have breaklines where the join is.
```

I have an arrow function that creates a string.

That string I pass as a message to a component that creates an alert.

Said component displays the message to the user.

So this is my arrow function:

```
export const confirmRemoval = (list: PersonalizedType[]): string =>
  'The following products already belong to a group and will be removed from it: ${list
    .map(v => `- ${v.name} belongs to the group ${v.groupName}`)
    .join(',')}. Do you wish to continue?';
```

How do I go about making the join statement create a new line in HTML? Is it possible to use only literal JS to do this or would I need to do something else?

Right now it serves the purpose it's needed by creating a comma between each message, but I kinda wish it would create a new line for a better user experience.

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm working with Angular 2+ on this project.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the formatting, I'm new to asking questions here.

Edit: Forgot to mention this but I've tried using '\n' and 'HTML breakline tag' in the join method but it didn't work.

Link from a working stackblitz with an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkyki9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem, especially the part with _"to a component that creates an alert"_.

Comment: I'll try it, once I get it done I'll update the post.

Comment: I'v added a link to the description.

Comment: The [mre] must include code in the question, not only on an external site. If StackBlitz goes out of business or that blitz gets deleted, this question will be of little use. Note that you can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here on SO.

Comment: There's only AngularJS in the snippet's options, and no Angular 2+.

I'm using Angular 8, what can I do to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)

Comment: Your previous answer already worked for me. both the innerHTML one and creating a template one (that only appears when the component receives a second, optional parameter which is the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is escaping the `<br>` tag for security reasons. You can explicitly bypass this by using the following binding:

```
<p [innerHTML]="message"></p>
```

See this question: [How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)

---

A better approach is to use templates without the need to manually generate new html tags:

```html
<ng-template #fooitem let-foo>
  - {{foo.name}} belongs to the group {{foo.groupName}}
</ng-template>

<ng-template #alert let-message>
  <p>{{message.header}}</p>
  <p *ngFor="let foo of message.foo">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="fooitem" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: foo }"></ng-container>
  </p>
  <p>{{message.footer}}</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="alert" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: message }"></ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3zftr

---

... or even better break up the templates in new sub-components.

Comment: Thank you so much!


Either of these solutions work for me (tho modifying it to use templates will be a hassle, but it'll probably save a lot more time down the line).

Once again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try joining on a `br` tag instead of a comma like this:

`.join("<br>")`

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that I've tried both that and newline ('\n') in it.

I've added this info to the post now, thanks for reminding me lol

Comment: The component that's consuming your output there must be scrubbing the string for html tags  if you're not seeing a line break,  what does it look like in the final source from the browser?

Comment: I've added a link to a working example from the description