# Angular removes leading whitespace when rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angular

At work, I am developing an Angular component that displays a string from its input on the rendered HTML page.
The HTML for displaying the string looks something like this:

```
<span>{{value}}</span>
```

where `value` comes from `this.value` in the Angular code. For normal strings this works OK, but I have found that Angular strips out leading whitespace. Now I know that HTML itself compresses multiple whitespace into one when rendering the HTML into a visible page, but the whitespace is removed from the HTML itself.
I have verified that the string in the Angular code contains whitespace:

```
console.log("The string is: [" + this.value + "]");
```

prints out `The string is: [   Hello world!]` on the web console. But what appears on the rendered HTML page is:

```
<span>Hello world!</span>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there leading spaces in `this.value`? Do you want whitespace or not? `console.log` doesn't do any processing like Angular does.

Comment: Maybe add a &nbsp; in the beginning?

Comment: Does <span [innerHtml]=“value”></span> help?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserveWhitespaces

Answer (score 2):

Even if Angular preserves the whitespace, which I assume it is doing, html will strip it down. You have two option to either use  tag or do it via css as shown below:

```html
No Preservation <br/>
<span> Hello world! </span><br/>
<span>   Hello world!  </span>


<br/>
With Pre tag

<pre>
  <span> Hello World!   </span>
</pre>

<br/>
With Css white-space: pre<br/>
<span style="white-space: pre;">
    Hello World!   </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use a non-breaking whitespace like this `const value = '&nbsp;Hello World!'`

Comment: Angular will strip the html tag because it sanitizes the value before rendering. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4