# How can i pass string and preserve formatting like <strong>

Tags: angular

I have a Angular form that on success routes to a new component that displays that the request was successful. To pass the info i use the history.state.data which works fine but i cant pass in a value with formatting.

the code i use looks like this

```
if (res.Success === true) {
  let email = this.form.value.email
  let message = `Your preference for <strong>${email}</strong> has been successfully updated !`
  this._router.navigate(['success'], {state : {data : {message: message}}}) 
}
```

then on the other component I read the message

```
this.message = history.state.data?.message
```

and in template

```
<p style="text-align: center;">{{message}}</p>
```

But my output looks like this, how can i make the  actually provide the
format vs just printing out ?

```
Your preference for <strong>ded@ede.com</strong> has been successfully updated !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use innerHtml attribute. Otherwise it will render it as text.

```
<p style="text-align: center;" [innerHtml]="message"></p>
```

See: [How to render string with html tags in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)