# Change innerHTML CSS style of iframes and images

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 6 app and I'm getting a blog entry from a HTTP call and I set one of the variables which is the content to the `innerHTML` of a `span` resulting in the blog content being displayed. It's also got images and iframes, and they do have style in there because they are defined in the editor. The problem I have is that the CSS I have to override the iframe values is not applied and I cannot get the desired result.

I have defined in my component.scss the following:

```
iframe {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

That CSS cannot be found in the list of CSS applied when I inspect the blog item rendered on the screen. I'm not sure whether that's because of the  I do after I retrieve the content or what but it doesn't simply show.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE: Adding component code:**

component.ts

```
@Component({
    animations: [enterScreenFromBottom],
    selector: 'app-blog-entry',
    templateUrl: 'blog-entry.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['blog-entry.component.scss']
})
export class BlogEntryComponent
```

...

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
            const id = p['id'];
            this.blogService.getById(id)
                            .then(b => {
                                this.blogEntry = b;
                                this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.blogEntry.content);
                                this.loading = false;
                            })
                            .catch(e => {
                                console.log('Error getting blog entry ' + id, e);
                                this.loading = false;
                            });
        });
    }
```

component HTML:

```
<div [@enterScreenFromBottom]="state">
    <p [innerHTML]="content"></p>
</div>
```

component scss:

```
iframe {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add your component code.

Comment: just updated the question with it - one sec, getting the right one

Comment: First, loading an iframe within a paragraph tag isn't valid HTML. Where does your CSS get added? Is it inline in the component? As an external file linked in the component?

Comment: It should get added as part of the component SCSS shouldn't it? OK - wrapping that up in a <p> is wrong. how should I render this then?

Comment: Not unless you direct the component to include it. If you're adding HTML that contains an iFrame, I would set the innerHTML on a div, section, etc. Just because you name the css file the same as the component, Angular doesn't automatically include it.

Comment: I get that, the scss is included as I include it on the styleUrl list in the component, I'm updating again the question

Comment: Hmm. You should be seeing component-targeted css in the DOM, since your component isn't overriding ViewEncapsulation.

Comment: I just hard coded the iframe after <div [@enterScreenFromBottom]="state" [innerHTML]="content"></div> and I can see the CSS being applied correctly. The code I pasted: <iframe width="400" height="345" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GzU8KqOY8YA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> it has to be related to the innerHTML thing

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None . Got this from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210786/style-not-working-for-innerhtml-in-angular-2-typescript

Comment: If figured it was something with encapsulation. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and quick replies!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help.