# Angular - InnerHtml with styles

Tags: angular

I've this...

```
const htmlVar = "<html>
<div style="display:flex">
<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
</div>
";
```

and on my html I've this..

```
 <div [innerHtml]="htmlVar"></div>
```

It's render everything, but the style :(

I attempted the solution of this link: [style not working for innerhtml in Angular 2 Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210786/style-not-working-for-innerhtml-in-angular-2-typescript)

but it's not working. Maybe because it's too old.

Any clue ?

Comment: Consider using the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to get this to work.

Comment: A `div` can't contain a `head` or `body`, that's invalid HTML

Comment: yes, @Liam..Just edited...but it's not the issue. Still continues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @R.Richards mentioned, use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer):

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
.
.
.
htmlVar: SafeHtml;

constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.htmlVar = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div style="display:flex; color: red;">
          <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>`);
}
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17ktd9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to illustrate

Also, as @liam already mentioned you should not have `<html>`, `<header>`, or `<body>` tags as `DIV`'s children