# The angular pipe does not work, so the style is not applied

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

The CSS defined in the HTML set by innerHtml is not reflected.

I tried to use bypassSecurityTrustHtml with pipe, but it doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569667/3717426

How can styles be applied appropriately?

working

```
<h1>Normal</h1>
<div class="navbar-brand mx-auto title">Test<br class="br-sp" />(Test)</div>
```

not working

```
<h1>innerHTML</h1>
<div class="navbar-brand mx-auto title" [innerHTML]="title | safeHtml"></div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/otera/innerhtml-css/tree/070baaff177d23ffd5d11802c2fee33d891255a1) for the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `ngModule` of your component of add `ViewEncapsulation` setted to **None**.
With default **Emulated** state, you component can't access to the styles with `innerHtml`.

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "app-head",
  templateUrl: "./head.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./head.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```