# Stop right scroll image that is shown dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angular, image, resize

I'm creating an application to create blog posts and show them.
The content of blog, along with the image data is stored as a string as HTML content. Upon retrieval in my Angular app, I'm doing:
`<div class="contentBox" [innerHTML]="post?.content"></div>`

Now I'm trying to wrap my images to fit the screen when viewed in mobile view but it always gets scrolled right. ( shown in the image as well)

[image]

To stop scrolling I tried

```
img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

It works perfectly when I try it using Inspect Element but when I add it in my code , it doesn't work.  I'm adding it like this:

```
.contentBox img {
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

How am I supposed to have this functionality working in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width: 100vw;` instead of `100%`.

> The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page.
>
> The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile
>   phone than on a computer screen.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: That's still the case when I apply it using Inspect Element. But when I add it in my code, it doesn't work

Comment: Does it has a parent container? We might have to look at the css applied on parent container(s) as well.

Comment: No. I've just given the present div a class name and accessing the image css in my code accordingly (have added in the question). I checked, my code is not picking up the img using `.contentBox img {}` in css

Comment: I had it working now following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44215795/6546277 . The issue was from the angular side. Anyways, thanks for the help @Manish