# innerHTML can't catch class from .scss in the component

Tags: html, css, angular

The code is in Angular 9.
Display the default paragraph.
Can't catch class from .scss in the component.

.HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlCode"></div>
```

.TS:

```
htmlCode: string = "<p class='newClass'>TEST</p><br>TEST<br>";
```

.SCSS:

```
.newClass{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML output?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210786/style-not-working-for-innerhtml-in-angular

Comment: @Chellappanவ it helps me a lot :) tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in styles code from scss, and encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

```
@Component({
  ...
  styles: ['
    .newClass{
       background-color: red;
    }
  '],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```