# How to insert HTML from server side in a component in angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular

suppose i want to insert some HTML element from the server side to the component, how can i do it

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
<div>
<h3>this is the container</h3>
  <div #holder></div>
</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('holder', { read: TemplateRef }) _template: TemplateRef<any>; 
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    debugger;
    this._template.createEmbeddedView('<div>this is a new "div" element</div>');       
  }
}
```

in this code i am trying to insert a div to another div with the id='holder' but i am not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the simple way to achieve.

**html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourHtml"></div>
```

**ts**

```
public yourHtml = '<div>this is a new "div" element</div>';
```

Comment: Was about to write this :P

Comment: But it's not the good way to deal lool
it would break pure element structure. Recommend way is use `cdk` and insert(but it only support component so it's more difficult).

Comment: i think this would not work, if my dynamically attached element has some events like click attached to it

Comment: I'm using the `safeHtml` which check if it's not hacked html. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute

Comment: Why don’t you add iframe?Is your html form web service or another component supported?

Comment: I suggest you to use Renderer2 class: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 and change server response to model which describe html elements

Comment: Check out this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/xducufDwLTejKGI4RT12?p=preview

Comment: i was thinking something like this - $( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
which we do in jQuery, is it not possible with angular4?

Comment: You can you hostlistener to handle you click or any single event what you want and your target element you append.

Comment: This solution would solve your problem when you use [innerHTML].

Comment: when i use this <div [innerHTML]="yourHtml"></div>
and use this 
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  yourHtml = '<div (click)="clicker()" style="border: solid 2px yellow; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">this is a new "div" element</div>';
i am not able to get the click event

Comment: My meaning is observer your external component click event , I would provide code later 