# InnerHTML in angular 4 is not loaded

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

i am working on @angular/core@4.4.6,

Here is my component html

```
<div class="contact" [innerHTML]="template">
```

here is my component ts code

```
this.template = '<div> hello world </div>';
console.log(self.template );
```

when the component ts code is running, the console can print out hello world, but this html is loaded to the component automatically, the  on the html page is still empty.

why is that and how to fix?

Comment: Any reason why you use `self` instead of `this`? It may be the reason why. `[innerHTML]="template"` refers to `this.template`, not `self.template`.

Comment: try placing `self.template = '<div> hello world </div>';` in the constructor of the component's class and see if it works.

Comment: show full code of a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to this and try,

```
self.template = '<div> hello world </div>';
```

If it is not working or you are still suffering try the following **jQuery** code(This is not a recommended way in Angular2)

**HTML**: `<div class="contact" id="template">`

**TS**:  `$('#template').html('<div> hello world </div>');`

Answer (score 2):

Some more context around your code snippet would be helpful. Things like how it's declared in the class, where is this initialization happening, is it exposed as a public member of the class are relevant.

However, my guess is that Angular doesn't trust the HTML as "safe".

For my needs I had to create a pipe to handle binding HTML markup to the template:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

/**
 * See link for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, args?: any): SafeHtml {
    if(value) {
      return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    } else {
      return 'Undefined HTML';
    }
  }

}
```

See the Angular docs for [Dom Sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) or follow the the link to the other SO post in the code comment for more info.