# Displaying HTML String in div using innerHtml

Tags: html, angular

I need to display raw HTML string using a div. I am assigning the HTML string to the innerHTML of a div like below

```
<div [innerHTML]="rawHTMLString">
</div>
```

However if the html string contains multiline comments or inline styles they too are displayed as text. See the issue on Stack Blitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jd32x).

Expected functionality is that the comments and inline style blocks should not be displayed. This is how it should be rendered.

[Expected result](http://scratchpad.io/amuck-vest-6852)

All the previous answers on Stack Overflow point to using div innerHTML. I know I am missing something trivial here, but I can't seem to figure out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: And you are dynamically loading/feeding the string? That is - you can't directly control the contents of the string?

Comment: You could try sanitizing the HTML string, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630507/1009922).

Comment: Yes. The string is auto generated from the server by a third party. So no control over the string generation.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

```
  safeHtml(html) {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
```

and in template,

```
  <div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(rawHTMLString)"></div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzngyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**