# Angular how to retain Html ID attribute when sanitized

Tags: angular

How can I only retain `id` part of the div when it sanitized, removing script part.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ue82rs?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

[Angular XSS](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss)

```js
import { OnInit, Component, Input, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `{{unsafe}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div [innerHtml]="unsafe">
    </div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

  output = 'heyo <div class="someclass" id="someid">sbang</div> <script>alert("bang");</script>';
  unsafe = this.output;


  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, this.unsafe));
    // heyo <div class="someclass" id="someid">sbang</div> <script>alert("bang");</script>
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.unsafe));
    // heyo <div class="someclass">sbang</div> 
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.STYLE, this.unsafe));
    // unsafe
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, this.unsafe));
    // heyo <div class="someclass" id="someid">sbang</div> <script>alert("bang");</script>
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL,this.unsafe));
    // error
  }
}
```

Result: [image: Imgur]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible. From looking at the source, the `id` attribute is not included in the array of approved attributes for sanitization:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts#L69

The call to the sanitization for HTML is made here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L159

It appears that you have to accept the defaults or disable with `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. Guess you could record the `id` attributes before the sanitization and add them back afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super fluent with the DomSanitizer but from what I found this seems to work:

```
console.log(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.unsafe));
```

Also, I found this other SO question which seemed to expand on it more:
[Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute)