# HTML not interpreting tags

Tags: php, html, angular, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am saving data into mysql using *htmlspecialchars()*. On output when getting data using *htmlspecialchars_decode()* before displaying it in **Angular**. But instead of interpreting the html code it is displaying it as a text.

Data in Database

```
&lt;p class=&quot;fr-tag&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;test&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Code being displayed after htmlspecialchars_decode()

```
<p class="fr-tag"><span>test</span></p>
```

Displaying the output from database into div as follows

```
<div *ngIf="product.pdescription" class="mt-2 product-description">{{product.pdescription}}</div>
```

I have also tried using *html_entity_decode* but didn't help.

Following is a screenshot of the browser

[image]

Comment: "I am saving data into mysql using `htmlspecialchars()`" ... why? That's completely unnecessary and is exactly why you're having problems right now...

Comment: what if there are special characters? The data is being entered into Rich Edit box.

Comment: Anyway... It looks like you're using a templating system, which probably takes care of escaping HTML for you. You'll need to use the template's "raw output" feature, assuming it has one.

Comment: MySQL is perfectly capable of handling "special characters" of all types.

Comment: Tried it without htmlspecialchars() and still same issue. HTML isn't interpreting the HTML tags.

Comment: Have you tried using innerHTML `<div *ngIf="product.pdescription" class="mt-2 product-description" [innerHTML]="product.pdescription"></div>`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!!! Please post that as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it working you should use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or outerHTML binding:

```
<div *ngIf="product.pdescription" ... [innerHTML]="product.pdescription"></div>
```

But beware about some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute)