# How to show dynamic created HTML string as HTML in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I've created Dynamic HTML (dropdowns) using TypeScript. When I try to show as innerHTML its shows options as text and not dropdown.

```
{{question.question}}
<div [innerHTML]="question.question" class="question-text"></div>
```

[image]

It should actually show me DropDowns..

Comment: try to use DomSanitizer (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)  and its `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` method. Process your HTML with this function prior to passing it to `innerHTML` property

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the html string in back quotes (` `) such that it is treated as a template string, also we can inject variables inside this string using `My name is ${name}!`
It is a native javascript ES6 feature so would work with any framework that uses javascript

Answer (score 0):

Angular will not let you render any HTML on the page as it might contain unsafe content. You have to tell Angular explicitly that your string is a safe string to render as HTML element.

The easiest way is to create custom pipe. Check the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630507/11367148)