# SAP Spartacus - Inline styles in Paragraph component (SmartEdit)

Tags: css, angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I've been trying to use one of the simplest OOTB features of the Paragraph component in SmartEdit (from a SAP Commerce fresh installation with the Spartacus storefront) - adding a color to some text in the Rich Text Editor - but it seems like the component sanitises the HTML therefore removing my styles.

Reproduction steps:

- On a fresh Spartacus v3.2.1 installation, access SmartEdit
- Add a Paragraph component:
  [image: Adding a Paragraph component in SmartEdit]
- Add some inline styles in the Rich Text Editor and save:
  [image: Paragraph component test data]
- Check the result:
  [image: Result of adding inline styles to Paragraph component]
- It's already pretty obvious that the Angular component removes the inline styles already, but just to confirm:
  [image: Network response containing the inline styles]

The obvious / simplest solution would be to:

1. create a `SafeHtmlPipe` to *leverage* the `DomSanitizer`
2. then extend the OOTB Paragraph component
3. and use the pipe on the desired element
   (as described in this other StackOverflow thread: [Angular2 innerHtml binding remove style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute))

BUT is this the expected OOTB behaviour or did I do something wrong while installing the project (or when I configured the settings)?

If it's the expected behaviour it would mean that some of the OOTB features can't actually be used without some coding and that's quite disappointing.

What do we do when we have lots of components using Rich Text Editors or HTML input fields? Are we going to extend them all?

Comment: `CMSParagraphComponent` is a CMS component type. If you modify ParagraphComponent implementation, the changes will be applied to all components of this type.

Comment: @WeizhengGao Is there a way to override a specific instance of a CMS component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is true that not everything works OOTB.

As you described, you can fix this issue by yourself, replacing the default `CMSParagraphComponent` with your custom one:

```
export const paragraphCmsConfig: CmsConfig = {
  cmsComponents: {
    CMSParagraphComponent: {
      component: YourParagraphComponent,
    },
  },
}
```

Inside of `YourParagraphComponent` you extend the given `ParagraphComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-paragraph',
  templateUrl: './your-paragraph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-paragraph.component.scss'],
})
export class YourParagraphComponent extends ParagraphComponent {}
```

and implement your own `SafeHtmlPipe`

```
<div class="your-paragraph" *ngIf="component.data$ | async as data" [innerHTML]="data.content | trust: 'html'"></div>
```

In our case, the Pipe was named `trust`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'trust',
})
export class YourSafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(
    value: any,
    type: string
  ): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)
      case 'style':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value)
      case 'script':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value)
      case 'url':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value)
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value)
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Hook all together in a module and import it into your custom implementation

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, CmsParagraphModule],
  declarations: [YourParagraphComponent],
  exports: [YourParagraphComponent],
  providers: [provideConfig(paragraphCmsConfig),YourSafeHtmlPipe],
})
export class YourParagraphComponentModule {}
```