# Angular 14: Attempting to use DomSanitized to avoid angular default sanitization causing errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I am attempting to leverage DomSanitized to avoid the default Angular sanitization like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630507/14108804

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";


@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class PageLoaderComponent implements PipeTransform {

    pageHtml: string;

    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
   }
```

HTML side:

```
<div (click)="pageClicked($event)" class="page-loader-wrap">
  <!--       [innerHTML]="pageHtml">-->
  <div class="page-loader-slot center-width narrow" [innerHTML]="pageHtml | safeHtml">

  </div>
</div>
```

However I get an error on the html page on `safeHtml`:

```
unresolved pipe: safeHtml
```

and an error on my class:

```
PageLoaderComponent is not declared in any Angular module
```

What is causing this and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a Pipe (which name is poorly chosen btw, you should rename it `SafeHtmlPipe` to show that it is a pipe).

As it is not declared standalone, you must have declared it in a module. You have to import this module in the module where you are using it.

I found this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safehtml-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsafe-html.pipe.ts) (not mine) that does exactly what you need. Don't hesitate to take inspiration on this